# Create map from array, grouping by field. Javascript. Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need to group a list of objects, based on the field "day" which is a string.

```
 diaImputaciones: Map<String, Array<ImputacionData>>;
```

I group my list by the string "day"

```
 _.chain(parte.imputacionesTarifaBase)
        .groupBy("dia")
        .map((imputaciones, dia) => ({ dia, imputaciones }))
        .value();
```

Error: Type '{ dia: string; imputaciones: ImputacionData[]; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Map'

---

I have also tried with this

```
 _.map(_.groupBy(parte.imputacionesTarifaBase, 'dia'), function (el, key) {
        return {
            key: key,
            values: _.map(el, function (item) {
                return [item];
            })
        };
    });
```

Error: Type '{ key: string; values: ImputacionData[][]; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Map'

---

But in no case do you let me assign the result to my Map.

How can I create a Map from my Array, grouping them by the "day" (string) field.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the result should be a map of key: value pairs. If so use [`_.mapValues()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mapValues) instead of `_.map()`:

```
 _.chain(parte.imputacionesTarifaBase)
        .groupBy("dia")
        .mapValues((imputaciones, dia) => ({ dia, imputaciones }))
        .value();
```

If you need a JS [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) you can use [`_.toPairs()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#toPairs), and wrap the expression with new Map:

```
 new Map(_.chain(parte.imputacionesTarifaBase)
        .groupBy("dia")
        .mapValues((imputaciones, dia) => ({ dia, imputaciones }))
        .toPairs()
        .value());
```